# Drawing a non-self-intersecting Polygon with R

Tags: r

Im trying to draw polygons with R with

```
ggplot()+geom_polygon(d,aes(x=lon,y=lat))
```

with d is a data frame file with 5 longitude and latitude coordinates.

But I got a self-intersecting polygon. How can I avoid the self-intersection

thanks

cheers

EDIt
`lon      lat
1 113.8638 27.63341
2 113.8602 27.63427
3 113.8626 27.63278
4 113.8528 27.65023
5 113.8568 27.63601
6 113.8593 27.62754
7 117.6790 39.01934
8 117.6790 39.01934
9 117.6790 39.01934`

Here are the coordinates, I want to draw a non self intersecting polygon based on those data points

Comment: You can select a subset by applying the function `chull()` to your dataset to avoid overlapping. With a reproducible example it would however be easier to provide a useful answer.

Comment: try like this `ggplot(data, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+geom_polygon()`

Comment: it doesn't work for me:(

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22805/how-to-draw-neat-polygons-around-scatterplot-regions-in-ggplot2) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the last three identical points in your list are a mistake and therefore discarding them, a non-overlapping polygon can be plotted with the rest of the data like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grDevices)
df1 <- read.table(text="lon lat
     113.8638 27.63341
     113.8602 27.63427
     113.8626 27.63278
     113.8528 27.65023
     113.8568 27.63601
     113.8593 27.62754",header=T)
df2 <- df1[chull(df1),]
p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=lon, y=lat))+
     geom_polygon(data=df2, aes(x=lon,y=lat, col=2, alpha=0.4) )+ 
     theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Things become more complicated if you don't want a convex polygon. You may then have to reorder the sequence of the points in your data frame and I'm not aware of a simple programmatic approach to solve this.